# wget.download() function shows HTTP Error 404

Tags: python, http, wget

when i run this

```
wget.download("http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760%20AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB")
```

It shows this Error Code

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

But when I run `wget http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760%20AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB` manually it works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated `wget.download` source code and there seems to be bug, piece of source code

```
if PY3K:
    # Python 3 can not quote URL as needed
    binurl = list(urlparse.urlsplit(url))
    binurl[2] = urlparse.quote(binurl[2])
    binurl = urlparse.urlunsplit(binurl)
else:
    binurl = url
```

so it make assumption URL needs to be quoted that is illegal character like space replaced by codes after `%` sign, but this was already done as your url contain `%20` rather than space. Your URL is altered although it should not

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
url = "http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760%20AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB"
binurl = list(urlparse.urlsplit(url))
binurl[2] = urlparse.quote(binurl[2])
binurl = urlparse.urlunsplit(binurl)
print(binurl) # http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760%2520AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB
```

You might either counterweight this issue by providing URL in form which needs escaping, in this case

```
import wget
wget.download("http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760 AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB")
```

xor use [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve), most basic form is

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER06808437M/1/7760%20AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB", "776 AIO-WIN10-A11-5VNTG.CAB")
```

where arguments are URL and filename. Keep in mind that used this way there is not progress indicator (bar), so you need to wait until download complete.